# Find the following limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} \operatorname{arccosh}(x) - \log_e x$

Tags: limits

Find the following limit using the fact that $ \operatorname{arccosh} (x) = \log_e \left(x + \sqrt {x^2-1}\right) $

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \operatorname{arccosh}(x) - \log_e x$$

Answer (score 3):

Following the hint, since $\log A-\log B= \log \frac A B$, we have

$$\operatorname{arccosh}(x) - \log x=\log \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt {x^2-1}}x\right)$$

then it suffices to determine

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt {x^2-1}}x$$

Answer (score 2):

The required limit is $\ln{2}$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \text{arccosh(x)}-\ln{x} &=\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln{\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)-\ln x}\\\\&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln{\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\right)}\\\\
&= \ln{\left(1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\right)}\\\\
&= \ln{\left(1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{|x|\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}\right)}\\\\
&=\ln{(2)}
\end{align}